# Make & show the same information as a command prompt

Tags: powershell

In my previous questions here on stack we determined my command should run like this.

```
(& C:\Gyb\Gyb.exe --email $DestinationGYB --action restore --local-folder $GYBFolder --label-restored $GYBLabel --service-account)
```

The problem with this is if I run that same command in a command prompt I would see a bunch of status information.
When I run the command as above all I see in VSCode is it ran that line and its waiting. How can I make it show me like the command prompt without opening a new window?

here is GYB
https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible for others in any way? I don't think many people own `C:\Gyb\Gyb.exe`.

Comment: its basically freeware that normally runs in a command prompt and gives a bunch of output while it runs @stackprotector

Comment: Then I suggest to at least share the source of that tool.

Comment: @stackprotector <https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses `()` around your command if you want to see the output at the same time. Otherwise, this behavior is expected and is not unique to the VSCode terminal.

---

The group-expression operator `()` is used to control the order of which code is executed in PowerShell. Expressions are evaluated like order of operations (re: PEMDAS) in Mathematics, the inner-most parentheses get evaluated first. You can also use the group-expression operator to invoke a property or method from the returned expression in the group.

The problem is, group-expressions don't output to the parent level directly, that only happens when the group-expression is done executing. So when you have something that can run for several minutes or even hours like `gyb.exe`, you don't see that output until the command exits and execution continues.

Contrast this to running outside of the group-expression; as STDOUT is written to the success stream the success stream is immediately written to console as it comes. There is no additional mechanism you are proxying your output through.

> **Note:** You will experience nearly the same behavior with the sub-expression operator `$()` as well, although do not conflate sub-expressions and group-expressions as they serve different purposes. Here is a link to the official explanation of the
> [**Grouping Operator `( )`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--), the [**Subexpression Operator `$( )**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--) is explained immediately below it.